# Group By to get count of occurrences of a unique combination and sum of it's transactions.

Tags: sql, group-by, count, sum, proc-sql

How do I get the count of the occurrences of a unique combination and the sum of it's transactions?

My data looks like this:

[image]

And I want this:

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? Postgres? Any other? What version?

Comment: I am using proc sql with SAS Enterprise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Customer,Bank,count(*) Count,sum(Transaction) Transaction
from yourtable
group by Customer,Bank
```

Comment: Dang, I was so close! Thanks.